# What's this strange syntax in AS3. Why does this make my browser hang//crash silently

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've stumbled over this in AS3.

```
while(y.t<ys) y.(y.t++, 0);
```

And I'm wondering, what's this strange dot parentheses syntax `.()` ? What is it supposed to do ?

Moreover i've tried a snippet of code including this in a browser and this make Flash hang//crash silently.
Any idea why ?

Thanks you

edit: The original code is there [as3-crypto](https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto/blob/master/src/com/hurlant/math/BigInteger.as#L531)

ps: I would infer it's some kind of dot notation followed by comma operator but i can't be sure at this point.

Comment: The only usage of **.()** out there in AS3 is a filter operator in E4X XML expressions: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#parentheses_(XML) Still, your example is not it and is probably just wrong.

Comment: Took it from there [as3-crypto](https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto/blob/master/src/com/hurlant/math/BigInteger.as#L531). The lib seems to work fine though.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer to it: https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto/issues/14

Comment: Actually it never came to me i would find answers on the very same repo, and on google if i simply pasted it.
Many thanks.
Since what this syntax do excatly will probably stay unanswered. Maybe you could repost your comment as answer so i can validate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I investigated that thing a bit. First, I located the mentioned [as3crypto repo](https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto/blob/master/src/com/hurlant/math/BigInteger.as#L531) and checked that the given code line is, indeed, there. The line there was not documented in any way and still makes no actual sense in AS3 terms.

Second, I viewed the deployed **SWC** library with decompiler, and, yet again, exactly that one place makes no sense and comes out malformed, which might be the sign that library was initially composed not in AS3 but maybe in HAXE.

Finally, I moved to the [repo issues](https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto/issues) section seeking for the way to inquire the owner about that line, but then I have just noticed that such an issue is already open: https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto/issues/14

So, the conclusion remains the same as I initially announced: it is not any valid AS3 syntax and probably just an error (maybe a translation mistake) in the repo.